# add value to a fresh created column for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create a new column (token) in my users table, and i want to affect a generated value to this column for each existing user. what i add is :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :generate_token

  private
     def generate_token
        self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(true, false)
     end

end
```

then i try to do :

```
rails console
> User.find_each(&:save)
```

but the new column still nil for each user.

when i try to save only one user :

```
user = User.first
user.save!
```

it gives me an error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

this is my validations from user model :

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

how i can solve this ?

Comment: Can you post the validations that are on this model?

Comment: password is a virtual attribute, don't exist really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using a `before_create` callback. Try using `before_save`.

Edit:

You'll need to skip validations to generate a token for your existing users. In the Rails console:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user.save!(validate: false)
end
```

Comment: also use it but no result

Comment: did you reload your rails console after changing the callback?

Comment: yes, it seem that there is a problem of validation, i update my question

Comment: i commented out the line validates :password and it seem works, i think this also will be working ;)

Comment: You don't need to comment out the validation. In this case, you just need to skip the validations when updating your existing users through the console.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're setting the password attribute anywhere, which is why the validation is failing.

Comment: Correct. In this case however, the OP doesn't want to set the password, as he is bulk updating the token field on his existing users. He just needs to skip the validations to perform the bulk update.